# Put an array into a section swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

After getting an answer on the forum I modified my code and here's my question:

1) After viewDidLoad() I make an array to feed a display

```
var sections = [
    Section(genre: " Event du mois",
            movies: ["The Incredibles", "The Incredibles"],
            expanded: false),
    Section(genre: " Top Event",
            movies: ["Guardians of the Galaxy", "The Flash", "The Avengers", "The Dark Knight"],
            expanded: false),
    Section(genre: " Event Fribourg",
            movies: ["The Walking Dead", "Insidious", "Conjuring"],
            expanded: false)
]
```

2) I'd like to replace this array with an array from my data base.

```
var sections = [Section]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myUrl = Constants.Path.APIview

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: myUrl)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = ""
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            //Convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json
                {
                    let eventMois = parseJSON["event"] as? NSArray

                    sections = eventMois

                }

            }catch {
                print(error)
        }

            }
        task.resume()

        }
```

I've this error message:**Cannot assign value to NSarray to type [Section]**
Can I put an array into a section?

Comment: What's a Section? And provide a sample of your JSON.

Comment: You are getting an `NSArray`, not your `Section` object. So you have to model your NSArray to Section first and then assign.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the NSArray also have to be of type `Section`. I'm guessing `eventMois` is of JSON type, so you want to convert that json to an array of `Section` objects, and then the compiler won't complain.

Comment: Thank you for your help
@EventMois is a array php encode to JSon.
how can i convert that json to an array of Section objects ?

Comment: @Kenpachi you'll have to write your own logic to extract relevant keys from the json dictionary and set it on your Section object

Comment: I worked well last night. I have redone all the script and I recover directly on the page in Json which comes from PHP and everything works thanks again